# Error with Oracle control file : no terminator found after TERMINATED and ENCLOSED field

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm loading data to a Oracle 10g database through a control file and i get this error :
no terminator found after `TERMINATED` and `ENCLOSED` field

My control file has a specific definition of separators and enclosed :

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," ENCLOSED by '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
```

And in the data in error, there is a big field in which we can find this text :

```
after an "unauthorized" IOS upgrade
```

I thought the `TERMINATED BY` and `ENCLOSED` were used to allow to have this kind of text in fields ..  can i fix the problem in the control file or do i have to fix the problem in the text file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Oracle reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10825/ldr_field_list.htm#sthref1063):

> `ENCLOSED` fields are read by skipping whitespace until a nonwhitespace
>   character is encountered. If that character is the delimiter, then
>   data is read up to the second delimiter. Any other character causes an
>   error.
>
> If two delimiter characters are encountered next to each other, a
>   single occurrence of the delimiter character is used in the data
>   value. For example, `'DON''T'` is stored as `DON'T`. However, if the field
>   consists of just two delimiter characters, its value is null.

So, use:

```
"data","after an ""unauthorized"" IOS upgrade ","data",...
```